# Intent Fail Android Java

Tags: java, android

Greeting everyone, i am an amateur android developer and I want to open an excel file with a button in my app but it just open the excel app but not the file I want to open, I've tried everything but there is something wrong that I did not notice maybe in the manifest or somewhere else.

Here is my code of the mainActivity please help me finding the error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button intentButton;
    private TextView tvContainer;
    private TextView linked;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intentButton = findViewById(R.id.intentButton);
        tvContainer = findViewById(R.id.tvContainer);
        linked = findViewById(R.id.linked);

        intentButton.setOnClickListener(abrirArchvo);

    }


    private View.OnClickListener abrirArchvo = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String directorioRaiz = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Excels/2-6.xlsx";
            System.out.println(directorioRaiz);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(directorioRaiz);
            System.out.println(uri.getPath());
            sendIntent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.ms-excel");
            String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title);

            if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(chooser);

            }
        }
    };

}
```

This is what debbug console shows as error:

**Waiting for application to start debug server**

**E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@8eec5a3
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@cf400a0**

**E/: APS:IFLoad:importExternalFunctions, search function createNewHwApsUtils failed, dlsym err:undefined symbol: createNewHwApsUtils**

Comment: If you are getting some kind of error, please do share it. If you do not, provide more details because something not working, can have too many root causes. Print more debugging info, tell us what they show...

Comment: To get a `Uri` for a file, use `Uri.fromFile()`, not `Uri.parse()`. Also, using a `file` `Uri` on Android 7.0+ will result in a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider` to serve up the file and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use in your `Intent`. Finally, bear in mind that you do not have access to your desired filesystem path on Android 10+ by default.